# Android, Error inflating при использовании Vector если API =< 19

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, vector-drawable

Имею кнопку:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/event_favourite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/favourite_selector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/event_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/event_title" />
```

Функционально это переключатель. Ничего необычного.

Фоном ставлю:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_filled" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_filled" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_empty" />
</selector>
```

`ic_favorite_filled`  и `ic_favorite_empty` это векторы, svg перегнаное в vector asset.

Всё работает и переключается на API => 21, но при меньших API вылетает с ошибкой:

`Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton`

В ходе расследования создал отдельный фон для API 19, где в качестве изображений использовались простые png:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/avatar_anon" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/avatar_deanon" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/avatar_anon" />
</selector>
```

И всё заработало.

Однако кнопок таких планируется много, и я хочу узнать: можно ли всё же как - нибудь использовать мои векторные `ic_favorite_filled` и `ic_favorite_empty` в качестве фона в API 19? Не хочу плодить лишние Drawable, их и без того очень много.

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857494/5330439) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795933/5330439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил благодаря ссылкам от TimurVI.

Убрал `android:background` и устанавливаю фон программно:

```
binding.eventFavourite.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.favourite_selector));
```